# Cannot resolve overloaded method 'createDataFrame'

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following code:

```
val data1 = Seq(("Android", 1, "2021-07-24 12:01:19.000", "play"), ("Android", 1, "2021-07-24 12:02:19.000", "stop"),
  ("Apple", 1, "2021-07-24 12:03:19.000", "play"), ("Apple", 1, "2021-07-24 12:04:19.000", "stop"))

val schema1 = StructType(Array(StructField("device_id", StringType, true),
  StructField("video_id", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("event_timestamp", StringType, true),
  StructField("event_type", StringType, true)
))

val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .appName("PlayStop")
  .getOrCreate()

var transaction=spark.createDataFrame(data1, schema1)
```

produces the error:

> Cannot resolve overloaded method 'createDataFrame'

Why?

And how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your schema consists of default `StructField` settings, the easiest way to create a DataFrame would be to simply apply `toDF()`:

```
val transaction = data1.toDF("device_id", "video_id", "event_timestamp", "event_type")
```

To specify custom schema definition, note that `createDataFrame()` takes a `RDD[Row]` and schema as its parameters.  In your case, you could transform data1 into a `RDD[Row]` like below:

```
val transaction = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(data1.map(Row(_))), schema1)
```

An alternative is to use `toDF`, followed by `rdd` which represents a DataFrame (i.e. `Dataset[Row]`) as `RDD[Row]`:

```
val transaction = spark.createDataFrame(data1.toDF.rdd, schema1)
```

Comment: Is there any performance difference between those 3 ways?

Comment: Given a Scala collection as the data source, #1 should be most efficient, as the other two ways require multiple transformations.  Between #2 and #3, I would prefer #2 since the other one involves transforming to a DataFrame twice.  That said, method `rdd` in #3 might be a very low-cost method (just for representing a DataFrame as `RDD[Row]`).  I suppose only comparative testing with some large datasets will be able to tell the difference conclusively.